# TeamCity: Delay build trigger if successful build detected in the past 1 hour

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, build-automation

We have a project using TeamCity which Triggers a build when changes are detected to the VCS with a 60 seconds quiet period.

I want to configure this trigger in such a way that the VCS trigger will not build if the last successful build was within 1 hours time. However, if there is no build detected in the past 1 hour and a change is detected in the VCS then the build should trigger instantly.

Is there a way I can achieve this task in TeamCity?

Thanks,
Vishal

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you want to trigger not more than one build per hour. Currently it is not possible to configure in TeamCity. Here is the related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-26302. Please vote for it.